# Python - Fail to generating bert embedding using multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, bert-language-model

I am trying to use BERT to generate word embedding for a list of word.

```
preprocess = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
small_bert = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-2_H-128_A-2/1'

bert_pre = hub.KerasLayer(preprocess)
bert_model = hub.KerasLayer(small_bert)

def word_embedding(sent):
    if type(sent)==str:
        sent = [sent]
    return bert_model(bert_pre(sent))['pooled_output']
```

The above code provied a function to get word embedding from a string/ list of string

The code works pretty fine and I am able to obtain the word embedding like the following

```
word_embedding("This is a dog")

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 128), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.9999982 ,  0.09135217, -0.9993329 ,  0.96194535, -0.9991869 ,
         0.07579318, -0.9892281 , -0.9668794 ,  0.06745824,  0.07896714,
        -0.81101316,  0.01557093, -0.11514608,  1.        , -0.9598647 ,
        -0.83923537,  0.8639652 ,  0.04229677, -0.9274309 ,  0.87699145,
         0.9675325 ,  0.02446483,  0.96745443,  0.9137065 , -0.99994516,
        -0.00484818, -0.9999251 ,  0.97071564,  0.9577635 ,  0.12064736,
         0.13986832,  0.01977904, -0.99208915,  0.1142559 ,  0.98749965,
         0.9999112 , -0.93131316, -0.05863096,  0.9166601 , -0.9995932 ,
         0.92014617,  0.94889516, -0.9995392 ,  0.9891672 , -0.9999985 ,
        -0.15958041, -0.99989873,  0.9984788 ,  0.9674587 ,  0.9849434 ,
         0.9884202 , -0.5348996 ,  0.07992988,  0.9977897 ,  0.99813277,
         0.9999679 , -0.99952024, -0.970687  ,  0.9040054 , -0.9458808 ,
         0.01751512,  0.36849502,  0.3939357 ,  0.9101836 , -0.15718344,
        -0.99999946, -0.44872832, -0.6077106 ,  0.96371555,  0.5564301 ,
         0.9982054 , -0.09481359, -0.9996993 ,  0.03875534,  0.65399134,
        -0.9902064 ,  0.66297245,  0.10515413, -0.97484773,  0.18679208,
        -0.5837009 , -0.12993163, -0.96478623, -0.99981767,  0.99985546,
        -0.98870945,  0.8561884 , -0.58723676, -0.68301636,  0.67417735,
        -0.9766185 ,  0.9956491 , -0.88204795,  0.99866074,  0.2829505 ,
         0.42085564, -0.9546872 , -0.8894943 , -0.9999068 , -0.97645766,
        -0.99447215,  0.97132486, -0.9995873 , -0.90443873, -0.9787839 ,
        -0.6670069 , -0.9991659 , -0.9913582 , -0.19619215,  0.9979996 ,
         0.99873877,  0.94075304, -0.76902175,  0.9997495 , -1.        ,
         0.06643485,  0.8816498 ,  0.83833504,  0.09686996, -0.9954674 ,
         0.22044522, -0.99998134, -0.5231443 ,  0.902108  , -0.9998227 ,
         0.97717   ,  0.9373147 ,  0.9990008 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

So uptill now, I can obtain the embedding of my target list of word in an iterative fashion.
But I think that is not effective at all and thus I am trying to parallize it using the following code.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty
pending=Queue()
for x in  list(model_pdf['JCOM']):
    pending.put(x)
def job():
    print("Started")
    kill=0
    while pending.qsize()>0:
        try:
            x = pending.get(block=True,timeout=2)
            print("Can I get some element?")
            word_embedding(x)
            print("Can I finish some embedding?")
        except Empty:
            return 1
job_list=[]
for x in range(60):
    job_list.append(Process(target=job))
for j in job_list:
    j.start()
for j in job_list:
    j.join()
```

However, after switching to this parallelizing version, I found that (from the print statement), I am able to get some element from the `pending` queue (The statement "Can I get some element" is being printed) but stuck at the word embedding step indefinitely, which I think some things going wrong. Since a single call of embedding takes 1-3 seconds only, and I found that no core is used by the Process ( checked via `htop`)

How can I solve this situation?

Here is my linux Os setting

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

with 64 cores and 64 gb memory

Comment: Mention your OS in the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion of and proposed solution for this (or at least a very similar) problem at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/15038